# SSH X11 Tunneling

Tags: java, user-interface, ssh, x11

I'm running Ubuntu 9.10 and trying to run a Java program I wrote whose source code is located on a remote machine. I'm using ssh to connect using the following command from the terminal:

```
ssh -X username@hostname
```

When running the program, one of the GUI frames has its buttons missing from view, but they are clickable and work as expected when I can guess accurately where they are. Running the code from my local machine they are present, and running from another windows machine using X-Windows they are present. Been trying to solve this problem for a few hours now but to no avail. Anyone have any helpful insight how to resolve this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using both Java 5.0 Swing toolkit and Compiz window manager? They tend to not like each other. Try use Java 6.0 or temporarily disable window effects.

Comment: I am compiling using Java 1.4.2 which is the latest version available on the server. I am running 1.6.0.15 on my local machine.

Comment: Try run: "export AWT_TOOLKIT=MToolkit" before starting your application.